# Dynamic css issue with jhipster

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jhipster

I implemented one template with my `jhipster` project. When I scroll down on web page, it adds one css class `fixed` in header tag. It is working fine normally and even with `Angularjs` but after implementing it in `jhipster`, it stopped working. I also found same issue with `carousel`. So, it looks like whichever is using real time update css, it is not working.

Please help me to sort this out.